# Телеграм бот не отвечает на упоминание его юзернейма в группе

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Проблема в том что бот не отвечает на его уопминание через @.
При чём, насколько я понял, он в целом не должен так делать из-за настроек приватности бота в BotFather, где указано, что при включеном состоянии бот должен отвечать на его упоминание в сообщении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эта настройка включена, но при этом бот никак не хочет откликаться на сообщение. К тому же на использование команд(вообще любых) он отвечает.
Нужны ли какие либо дополнительные хандлеры что бы он мог видеть свое упоминание? Пишу на python библиотекой pytelegrambotAPI

```
import telebot
import openai
from threading import Thread
import time

bot_name="@botname"

token="token"

bot=telebot.TeleBot(token)

# Set up OpenAI API client
openai.api_key = "api"

picture_verbs=[ 'portray','depict', 'illustrate', 'render', 'express', 'delineate', 'sketch', 'draw',
               'изображать', 'отобразить', 'нарисовать', 'нарисовывать', 'наделить образом', 
               'изобразить в рисунке', 'намалевать', 'находить воплощение', 'изобразить на картике', 'нарисовать скетч',
               'изобрази', 'отобрази', 'нарисуй','прорисуй','' 'нарисовывай', 'надели образом', 'изобрази в рисунке', 'намалевай',
                'находи воплощение', 'изобрази на картике', 'нарисуй скетч', 'сгенерируй','сгенерировать',
                'зобразити', 'відобразити', 'намалювати', 'наділити обрисами', 'зобразити в малюнку', 'знайти втілення',
                  'зобразити на картинці', 'намалювати ескиз', 'зобрази', 'відобрази', 'намалюй', 'наділи обрисами', 
                  'зобрази в малюнку', 'знайди втілення', 'зобрази на картинці', 'намалюй ескиз'
               ]

first_message={"role": "system", "content": "Ти добрий асистент. Ти повинен відповідати людям на тій мові, на якій вони тебе питають."}
history={}

#адаптация сообщения для генерации картинки
def adapt(message): 
    for word1 in message.split():
        for word2 in picture_verbs:
            if word1==word2:
                message=message.split(word1,1)[1] 
                return message
    return False

#генерация картинки
def generate_picture(message):
    response = openai.Image.create(
        prompt=message,
        n=1,
        size="1024x1024"
    )   
    return response['data'][0]['url']

#генерация ответа
def generate_reply(user_id):
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
         messages=history[user_id],
        max_tokens=1000
        )
    return response['choices'][0]['message']['content'] 



@bot.message_handler(commands=['help', 'start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    user_id=message.from_user.id
    if user_id in history:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Yeah, I remember you.")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hi! How can I help you?",  reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)





@bot.message_handler(commands=['clear'])
def clear_history(message):
    user_id=message.from_user.id
    history[user_id]=[first_message, ]
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Dialogue history was cleared", reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)

    
# Define a handler for text messages

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True )
def send_reply(message):
    
    if bot_name in message.text or message.chat.type == "private" or message.reply_to_message and message.reply_to_message.from_user.id == bot.get_me().id:
        gen_words=adapt(message.text.lower())
        if gen_words:
            a=False
            def send_action():
                while a==False:
                    bot.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, 'upload_photo')
                    time.sleep(5)
            th=Thread(target=send_action, args=())
            th.start()
            try:
                generate_picture(gen_words)
                bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, generate_picture(message.text))
            except openai.error.InvalidRequestError:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Sorry,your request was rejected as a result of our safety system. Try something different.")   
            a=True  


        else:
            
            a=False
            def typing_action():
                while a==False:
                    bot.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, 'typing')
                    time.sleep(5)
                    

            th=Thread(target=typing_action, args=())
            th.start()

            # gettin id of current user
            user_id = message.from_user.id

            if user_id in history:
                history[user_id].append({"role":"user", "content":message.text})
            else:
                history[user_id]=[first_message, {"role":"user", "content":message.text} ]

            
            bot.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, 'typing')
            # Call OpenAI's GPT-3 API to generate a reply
            try:
                reply=generate_reply(user_id)
            except openai.error.InvalidRequestError:
                history[user_id]=[first_message, {"role":"user", "content":message.text} ]
                response = generate_reply(user_id)
                reply = "The previous chat history was cleared to prevent the limit exceeding.\n" + response
            except:
                reply="Sorry, something went wrong."
            
            a=True
            history[user_id].append({"role": "assistant", "content": reply}) #save gpt reply

            # Reply to the user with the generated reply
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, reply,  reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)



bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: Так покажите существующий код

Comment: @ClarkDevlin  я то прикрепил, но как это поможет? В этом коде к тому же я обошел проблему, правда теперь в группе бота нужно делать админом.